# How do I add a svg icon next to my dl item?

Tags: html, css, svg, html-lists

I created a dl list with dt and dd items. I would like to find out how I can add a css style to my dt which will include a svg icon before the dt. This is the link to the svg icon: http://www.urs.co.za/test/assets/images/icon_25_bullet.svg

```
<dl>
<dt><strong>Grow your customer list with Store Master </strong> </dt>
to effortlessly capture your customer's details whilst processing the sale. Communicate with your  customers and encourage them to return by notifying them about discounts and promotions.</dd></dl>
<br>
<dl>          
<dt><strong>Get better business insight and increase your sales with powerful inventory management</strong></dt><br>
<dd>Categorize your products by name, type, brand, supplier, etc for quick and efficient stock takes and insightful reporting. Save time with bulk product changes.</dd>
<br> 
<dt><strong>Barcodes and labels</dt>
</strong><br><dd>Create and print barcodes and labels making it easy for you to add products to sales, IBT’s or stock takes.</dd><br>
</dl>
```

Comment: Can you include your html please?

Comment: @TrueTiem Thanks, I tried that. It's not showing up. Any idea why?

Comment: @MelenthaBisetty i forgot to add display. Try my answer

Comment: @TrueTiem Works perfectly thank you so much!

Comment: Sure, @TrueTiem how do i do this?

Answer (score 1):

```
dt:before {
    content: " ";
    background: url("http://www.urs.co.za/test/assets/images/icon_25_bullet.svg");
    background-size: contain;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

will work perfectly.